# Swift 4 map not showing users current location

Tags: swift

I'm trying to show the users current location on the map but nothing is working. Where am I going wrong?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var mapView: MKMapView?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    let distanceSpan: Double = 500

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupNavBar()
        setupMapView()
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    fileprivate func setupNavBar() {
        self.navigationItem.title = "Near By"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDissmiss))
    }

    fileprivate func setupLocationManager() {self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

    fileprivate func setupMapView() {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.mapView?.showsUserLocation = true
        self.mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: (self.window?.frame.width)!, height: view.frame.height))
        self.view.addSubview(self.mapView!)
    }
```

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I’d suggest excising all of this `UIWindow` and `UIScreen.main.bounds` related code. Just reference `self.view.bounds` and be done with it. Not only is this unnecessary, but you’ll eventually get yourself in trouble (e.g. multitasking where you don’t take up the whole device screen, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `showUserLocation` property before allocating your mapView.

In the future, to avoid this kind of mistake, you can use a different coding style where you don't use optional e.g.

```
 fileprivate func setupMapView() {
    let mView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
    mView.showsUserLocation = true
    view.addSubview(mView)
    self.mapView = mView
}
```

In addition, make sure your `Info.plist` contains the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key - as documented https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html